# NPM installation issue in virtual machine

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am working on an angular project in a virtual machine. Each time I trying to do npm install, it's creating a .stagging folder and throwing error. Till now I have tried the following procedures.

1. deleted package-lock.json
2. npm cache clean --force
3. npm install

Each time I am running the command npm install, it's throwing a different kind of error.

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...osoft.com"
npm ERR! } ],'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\a674400\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-08T13_02_31_388Z-debug.log

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to delete the `node_modules` folder too?

Comment: post your error messages?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Yes each time I used to delete the node_modules.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...osoft.com"
npm ERR! } ],'

 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\a674400\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-08T13_02_31_388Z-debug.log

Comment: Try this 1) upgrade npm 2) clean the cache 3) npm instal -j package name, did this work?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra my npm is up-to-date and every time I clean the cache by running npm cache clean --force. Installing individual packages is possible I am not getting the issue

Comment: does your vm has bridged connection or nat connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Below are the steps.

1. Uninstall node js and install it again from the https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Delete all npm\node remnants
3. Set up environment variables by typing ENV in windows search and launch and set the following variables as per requirement
4. Variable name - http_proxy,
   Variable value - http.proxy.abc.com:8000
5. Variable name - https_proxy,
   Variable value - http.proxy.abc.com:8000
6. Variable name - no_proxy,
   Variable value - .abc.com
7. Variable name - proxy,
   Variable value - http.proxy.abc.com:8000
8. restart your virtual machine and then do NPM install
9. Also do clone you project in local folder not in cloud as in one drive. Please be careful with the folder path as well.